# Finding the unknown constant of a PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$f(x) = ke^{-x^2 / 2} $$ from negative infinity to positive infinity.
I know that in order to find the constant you integrate the pdf with the limits and set it equal to 1. Unfortunately I haven't figured how to integrate $$ e^{-x^2/2}$$.

Comment: Ever met a *gaussian* distribution before?

Comment: The normal distribution. Yes.  I see the form is similar but I don't see how you use it to solve for k.

Comment: So, which gaussian density do you know? Please be specific.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by guassian densities. There are more then one? I was referring to the normal with pdf (1/sqt(2pi)sigma) * e^((x-mu)^2/(2 sigma^2).

Comment: Well yes there are more than one--since these are indexed by mu and sigma^2. OK, so you know gaussian densities, then what is missing to answer your own question?

Comment: So k = 1/sqrt(2pi) sigma e^(mu^2). I don't see it.

Comment: You have to determine the unique mu and the unique sigma^2 involved in the density which interests you.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: I would compare the "pdf (1/sqt(2pi)sigma) * e^(-(x-mu)^2/(2 sigma^2))" (your own comment, slightly corrected) with the function in your post.

Comment: So it is a normal~(0,1)? and k would equal 1/sqrt(2pi)?

Comment: It seems so, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for the help.